# How to update the status automatically after 15 days?

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a date and status column in a MySQL table. currently status of post is = Sent/Received. All i want to change the status = Aborted after 15days automatically.

Query:

```
 if (txtrecdate.Text == "" && ddlstatus.SelectedItem.Text != "Completed")
     {
         queryStr = "update barter_proposals set website_a=?web_a,email_id=?email,email_id2=?email2,email_id3=?email3,contact_name=?cname,proposal_status=?status,reason=?rsn," +
              "comment1=?com1 ,agreement=?agreement,agrmt_filename=?agrmt_filename,comment2=?com2,comment3=?com3,lifespan_date=?lpdate where pro_id=?pro_id";
     }
```

I googled it and found this solution:

```
UPDATE table SET status = "Aborted" where date=DATE_ADD(date, INTERVAL 15 DAY)
```

How to apply this in my update query? Is there any other way to change the status automatically after 15 days?

Comment: write a sql job and run it daily. Check for the date which is 15 days old from sysdate, for such a data, update the status as Aborted. If you do not want that in sql, do that in either in a windows service or azure web job or task scheduler. You can look at Hangfire as well

Comment: Well, if you want to do that in  _"C#"_ level, you have several options, i.e. create service which will execute your code when time comes or use Windows Task Scheduler.

Comment: Or you can also create a function wherein if the user logged in/ visit the system, the function will check the date. If the date is over 15 days then update the status, if not then do nothing.

Answer (score 2):

Look into MySQL events. First of all you'll need to turn on event scheduler on MySQL side

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/events-configuration.html

and then create event

```
delimiter $$

CREATE EVENT update_table_statuses
    ON SCHEDULE
      EVERY 1 DAY STARTS '2018-03-22 23:00:00'
    DO
      BEGIN
        UPDATE table SET status = "Aborted" where date=DATE_ADD(date, INTERVAL 15 DAY);
      END $$

delimiter ;
```

Event will be executed once a day

Comment: i dint understand where condition.what it will do? date=DATE_ADD(date, INTERVAL 15 DAY)

Comment: Heh, well the query inside event was copied from your question. Perhaps you've meant `date = date_sub(now(), interval 15 day)` but who knows

Comment: yup @alexey ...actually i am doing changes on live server...so i just wanted to confirm it whether that condition update the status after 15 days..

Comment: your original won't do anything as it's always false, the one above should do the trick. also I would replace `=` with `<=`